# Using DBup with octopus deploy error, (System.Data.SqlClient is not supported on this platform.)

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-core, octopus-deploy, dbup

I'm using .net core 2.1 project with DBUP library, but when I try to run the DBUP inside octopus deploy the migration tool is returning an error **System.Data.SqlClient is not supported on this platform.**

I followed all these steps from an Octopus Documentations https://octopus.com/blog/dbup-database-deployments...

Already did this steps to fix the problem but without success:

- net core SDK 2.1, 2.2 installations on the target server
- Restart the server
- New release with System.Data.SqlClient nuget package associated with the DBUP Project

Not sure what I can do more to fix this issue

[image: System.Data.SqlClient is not supported]

Comment: In windows or linux ?

Comment: Hi @Niraj Gajjar, in windows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem, DBUP project needs to be published isolated from other projects.

My bad was, trying to run/use dbupproject.dll file as a reference from other projects.